# node.js generic function execution using function.prototype.apply

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a bunch of action methods such as:

```
function doA(x, y, callback){

  .. some additional logic here ...

  do_something_async(x, y, function(result) {
    callback(result);
  });
}
function doB(x, y, z, callback){

  .. some additional logic here ...

  do_something_async2(x, y, z, function(result) {
    callback(result);
  });
}
```

And I'd like to create a generic execution function such as:

```
function doCommand(fn) {
  // Execute the fn function here with the arguments
  // Do something with the result to the callback from the action function
  // (which may require running the action function again...)
}
```

The function `doCommand` will receive as a first argument the name of the action command and the rest of the arguments will be as required by the action command. In other words:
`doCommand(doA, 5, 10, cbfn);` will call `doA` with the relevant arguments. And `doCommand(doB, 1, 2, 3, cbfn)` will call `doB` with the relevant arguments.

So far, my `doCommand` function looks like this:

```
function doCommand(fn) {
    fn.apply(null, arguments);
}
```

However, I have no idea how to capture inside `doCommand` the value of result after the async function execution because based on this value I may need to do something in addition, for example, run the action function again.
Plus, this will require a change the signature of every action command to disregard the first `null` argument created by the `apply` function.

I'm pretty sure there is a smarter way to do this. Would appreciate your help in finding out how.

Thanks!

EDIT:
A typical action function would look like this:

```
function doA(arg1, arg2, cb) { 
    ... some logic using arguments ... 
    asyncmodule.once('event', function(event) { 
        ... do something ... 
        callback(event.result); 
    }); 
    asyncmodule.send('A command', [list of specific arguments]); 
}
```

The caller to the action function needs to do something with the result, however for specified failure results, there needs to be either a repeat or changing of arguments and retry.

Comment: can you call `fn` directly where you call `doCommand`?

Comment: The issue is that I need to act the same for all action functions in case of specific value in the result. And I do not want to write it every time after calling the action function. I have about 50 different action functions with different signatures.

Comment: And as I said in the OP, I may need to execute the action function again based on the value of result (or maybe more than once and enter additional logic).

Comment: in fact, you don't need that anonymous function expression, so `doA = do_something_async` and `doB = do_something_async2` would suffice.

Comment: @Bergi, I can't replace the action functions. There's more logic that goes on inside these functions. I simplified it for the sake of the discussion. I'll correct it in the OP to avoid confusion

Comment: Is that additional logic before the invocation of `do_something_async`, or is it in the callback as well?

Comment: Added clarification to the OP about the logic inside the action function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a pretty strong convention of the callback being the final argument to a function, so I'll assume you're using that.  We'll start by fixing up the arguments and injecting our own callback, and then we can call the function and be on our way.

```
function doCommand(fn) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); // We want a real array
    args = args.slice(1); // Otherwise it contains fn, which isn't right
    var finalCallback = args[args.length - 1]; // We'll need this at the end
    args = args.slice(0, -1); // But we don't need it now
    fn.apply(null, args.concat( function() { // This looks weird, but it allows us
                                             // to keep the callback inline with
                                             // the function call
        // Here you can operate on the results
    }));
}
```

Note that `concat` is non-destructive, so you can call `fn` like that as many times as you like with different callbacks.  Don't forget to eventually call `finalCallback`!

As Bergi points out, you can combine all of the slices - I just pulled them apart so I could comment them better:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1, -1)
```

And you'd have to pull the `finalCallback` out of `arguments` instead of `args`, of course.

Comment: This what I was looking for! Tested it and it works. Beautiful. Thanks @Aaron!!

Comment: Better use `slice` instead of `Array.apply`, even if you're not going to pass a (single) number as the first argument.

Comment: @Bergi I've seen it done both ways.  Why the preference for `slice`?

Comment: As I said, because `Array.apply(null, [5])` doesn't work. And of course, you could save a lot lines here by just doing `var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1, -1)` :-)

Comment: Yeah, the slices could definitely be combined, but I wanted to be able to comment on them separately.  I meant to make a note of that at the end, but forgot.

Comment: For the sake of education, what's the purpose of the `args.concat` and is it needed?

Comment: @Ozk Remember that `Function::apply` expects all of the arguments to the function in an array.  `args.concat` allows us to create an array with the passed-in args, plus the callback so that we can control what is done with the results.

Comment: @Aaron, I somehow missed it, but it is definitely clear now ^^ thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a practical way of identifying which argument is a callback function, I don't see a good way to do this.

However, this is yet another place where using promises instead of callbacks would make an asynchronous task simpler. If your async functions used promises instead of callbacks, then you could do this:

```
function doA(x, y){
  return do_something_with_promises(x, y);
}
function doB(x, y, z){
  return do_something_with_promises2(x, y, z);
}

function doCommand(fn) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

    return fn.apply(null, args)
    .then(function (result) {
        if (result === "run me again!") {
            return fn.apply(null, args);
        }
    });
}

doCommand(doA, "Hey!", "Hey!")
.then(function (result) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, thanks @JLRishe for the quick response. My application as it is now is fundamentally based on async execution mostly with async.js, so I'm not sure I can switch now to promises. But I may need to think about it.